# Unable to deserialize "MenuRespose" in this XML response

Tags: c#, xml

I'm unable to deserialize `MenuRespose` in this XML response:

```
<LOGIN_REQUEST_RET>
<ERRMSG>Processed successfully.</ERRMSG>
<ERR_NUMBER>0</ERR_NUMBER>
<ERROR_FOUND>No</ERROR_FOUND>
<ProductID>1518</ProductID>
<MYCHOICE>1</MYCHOICE>
<MenuResponse>
  <SSMenus>
   <Mtemp>
      <ControlID>100</ControlID>
      <MenuName>My Card</MenuName>
      <SubMenuName>Card Summary</SubMenuName>
      <IsChecked>1</IsChecked>
   </Mtemp>
   <Mtemp>
      <ControlID>101</ControlID>
      <MenuName>My Card</MenuName>
      <SubMenuName>Card Summary</SubMenuName>
      <IsChecked>1</IsChecked>
   </Mtemp>
   <Mtemp>
      <ControlID>102</ControlID>
      <MenuName>My Card</MenuName>
      <SubMenuName>Statement</SubMenuName>
      <IsChecked>1</IsChecked>
   </Mtemp>
   <Mtemp>
      <ControlID>103</ControlID>
      <MenuName>My Card</MenuName>
      <SubMenuName>Recent Activity</SubMenuName>
      <IsChecked>1</IsChecked>
   </Mtemp>
   <Mtemp>
      <ControlID>104</ControlID>
      <MenuName>My Card</MenuName>
      <SubMenuName>Alerts</SubMenuName>
      <IsChecked>1</IsChecked>
   </Mtemp>
   <Mtemp>
      <ControlID>105</ControlID>
      <MenuName>My Card</MenuName>
      <SubMenuName>Lost/Stolen Card</SubMenuName>
      <IsChecked>1</IsChecked>
   </Mtemp>
   <Mtemp>
      <ControlID>106</ControlID>
      <MenuName>My Card</MenuName>
      <SubMenuName>Cardholder Agreement</SubMenuName>
      <IsChecked>0</IsChecked>
   </Mtemp>  
  </SSMenus>
</MenuResponse>
<ORIG_CURRENCY_CD/>
<CURR_DESC/>
<REMITTANCE_FLAG/>
<CLIENTID>1000</CLIENTID>
</LOGIN_REQUEST_RET>
```

To deserialize this, I am using following properties:

```
[XmlElement("MenuResponse ")]
public MenuResponse MenuResponse { get; set; }
```

---

```
[Serializable]
public class MenuResponse
{      
    public SSMenus SSMenus { get; set; }
}

public class SSMenus
{  
    public List<Mtemp> Mtemp { get; set; }
}

public class Mtemp
{
    [XmlElement("SKey")]
    public string SKey { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ControlID")]
    public string ControlID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("IsChecked")]
    public string IsChecked { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("LogoAcctid")]
    public string LogoAcctid { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Menu")]
    public string Menu { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SubMenu")]
    public string SubMenu { get; set; }
}
```

When I am trying to deserialize the output is as below:

> menuReponse : Count (0)

Can anybody help? I spent a lot of time with this.

Comment: The serialization need to start at the root level of the xml.  So you need to add a class for LOGIN_REQUEST_RET.

Answer (score 0):

Add root class if you don't have it yet

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("LOGIN_REQUEST_RET")]
public class Response
{
    public MenuResponse MenuResponse { get; set; }
}
```

change MenuResponse to

```
[Serializable]
public class MenuResponse
{
    public List<Mtemp> SSMenus { get; set; }
}
```

remove `SSMenus` class

And use [xsd.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe) to generate classes from xml